set S3Logger log level to only log INFO messages
write python code to set S3Logger log level to only log messages of "INFO" and above
I define the log function as
log = S3Logger(ETL_LOG_BUCKET, INGESTION_HANDLING_LOG_PREFIX).log
but only want the S3Logger to show INFO and ERROR messages
